# mysql grant option

Tags: mysql, permissions

I have a mysql user that currently has the following privileges:

```
mysql> show grants;
+--...--+
| Grants for debian sys-maint@localhost
+--...--+
| GRANT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, CREATE, DROP, RELOAD, SHUTDOWN, PROCESS, FILE, REFERENCES, INDEX, ALTER, SHOW DATABASES, SUPER, CREATE TEMPORARY TABLES, LOCK TABLES, EXECUTE, REPLICATION SLAVE, REPLICATION CLIENT, CREATE VIEW, SHOW VIEW, CREATE ROUTINE, ALTER ROUTINE, CREATE USER, EVENT, TRIGGER ON *.* TO 'debian-sys-maint'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD '*DA604C65D4EFF216D1F61FCD42726FA881FB6562' WITH GRANT OPTION |
+--...--+
```

I'd like it to be able to do that to another user:

```
mysql> grant all privileges on *.* to 'foo'@'%' identified by 'bar';
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'debian-sys-maint'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `sys-maint@localhost` user doesn't have `ALL` privileges. It's lacking the `CREATE TABLESPACE` privilege.

If your user really had `ALL` privileges then when you did a `SHOW GRANTS;` you'd see:

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'debian-sys-maint'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD '*DA604C65D4EFF216D1F61FCD42726FA881FB6562' WITH GRANT OPTION
```

To be able to do a `GRANT ALL` on another or new user, the user issuing the `GRANT ALL` must themselves have every permission or the grant will fail.

To grant your 'sys-maint@localhost' user `CREATE TABLESPACE` permissions issue the following command from an account that does have enough rights to do so (e.g. root):

```
GRANT CREATE TABLESPACE ON *.* TO 'sys-maint@localhost';
```

Or when logged in as `sys-maint@localhost` (and this works on MySQL 5.5) do the following:

```
USE mysql;
UPDATE user SET `Create_tablespace_priv`='Y' 
            WHERE user='sys-maint' AND host='localhost';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

Logout then log back in again (`QUIT` if using the command line `mysql` client or disconnect if using a GUI client such as HeidiSQL) and `sys-maint@localhost` should be able to issue the `GRANT ALL` command.

This works because your `sys-maint@localhost` already has sufficient privileges to update the `user` table.

And as always, when tinkering with MySQL permissions, remember to do a `FLUSH PRIVILEGES;`

Comment: It seems though that the FLUSH PRIVILEGES is not sufficient. I have to disconnect the session and reconnect before I can grant to the other user.

Comment: @JohannesErnst - I did mention that near the end "Logout then log back in again".

Comment: @JohannesErnst - anyhoo....did it work?

Comment: Yes, it does work. Thank you. The trick looking for the summary "all privileges" in the "show grants" is worthwhile to know.